# Code for finding the middle letter of a name in "babynames" dataset is giving faulty result when the name has 6 letters

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-science

I am trying to solve an exercise question from [R for data science (2E)](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/strings.html#exercises-2) of chapter 16 (16.5.4 question no. 1) which requires to extract the middle letter of every name of the dataset. So I wrote the code below to find the middle letter if the name has *odd* number of letters or the middle two letters if the name has *even* number of letter.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(babynames)

   babynames |>
   mutate(
    length = str_length(name),
    middle = if_else((length / 2) %% 2 != 0, 
             str_sub(name, ceiling(length / 2), ceiling(length / 2)),
             str_sub(name, length / 2, (length / 2)+1)
    )
   )
```

Now the code gives me my expected result **except when the name has 6 letters**. Instead of extracting the middle two letters *it shows only the first of the two letters*

```
    # A tibble: 1,924,665 × 7
    year sex   name          n   prop length middle
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <int>  <dbl>  <int> <chr> 
 1  1880 F     Mary       7065 0.0724      4 ar    
 2  1880 F     Anna       2604 0.0267      4 nn    
 3  1880 F     Emma       2003 0.0205      4 mm    
 4  1880 F     Elizabeth  1939 0.0199      9 a     
 5  1880 F     Minnie     1746 0.0179      6 n     
 6  1880 F     Margaret   1578 0.0162      8 ga    
 7  1880 F     Ida        1472 0.0151      3 d     
 8  1880 F     Alice      1414 0.0145      5 i     
 9  1880 F     Bertha     1320 0.0135      6 r     
10  1880 F     Sarah      1288 0.0132      5 r     
# … with 1,924,655 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I don't understand why the code is making an exception for the names with 6 letters. What can be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check for odd/even values is incorrect. Look at

```
data.frame(length=1:10) |>
  mutate(compare=(length / 2) %% 2 != 0)
#    length compare
# 1       1    TRUE
# 2       2    TRUE
# 3       3    TRUE
# 4       4   FALSE
# 5       5    TRUE
# 6       6    TRUE
# 7       7    TRUE
# 8       8   FALSE
# 9       9    TRUE
# 10     10    TRUE
```

Notice that's not triggering correctly for even/odd values. The extra `/2` in there is checking that numbers are actually divisible by 4. You should be using

```
babynames |>
  mutate(
    length = str_length(name),
    middle = if_else(length %% 2 != 0, 
                     str_sub(name, ceiling(length / 2), ceiling(length / 2)),
                     str_sub(name, length / 2, (length / 2)+1)
    )
  )
#     year sex   name          n   prop length middle
#    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <int>  <dbl>  <int> <chr> 
#  1  1880 F     Mary       7065 0.0724      4 ar    
#  2  1880 F     Anna       2604 0.0267      4 nn    
#  3  1880 F     Emma       2003 0.0205      4 mm    
#  4  1880 F     Elizabeth  1939 0.0199      9 a     
#  5  1880 F     Minnie     1746 0.0179      6 nn    
#  6  1880 F     Margaret   1578 0.0162      8 ga   
# ...
```